# VS 22 - How to find in the code which lines have these two words

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual studio 2022
How to find in the code which lines have these two words, example:

find line that has the word 'return' and 'xdto'

Line found: return Json(xdto);

I tried searching with ctrl+f and the text 'return*xdto'

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable regular expressions (reg-ex) to use wildcards in searches.

Try ctrl-shift-f to search in all files.

If you need help with the syntax of regular expressions, do a search first and if the answer isn't there, post a new question with a reg-ex tag.

EDIT: sometimes reg-ex is indicated by a small button containing the symbols '.*'